# Create kendo dropdown dynamically in one method and assign datasource in another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have to create kendo dropdownlist dynamically based on number of id's I received.I have created one method in which i am looping on id and creating dropdown with that id. It is not like that all dropdown will created at the same time dropdown are created on change of parent dropdown. Datasource of this dropdown are same...so how can i assign datasource to dropdown currently i am getting **datasource of undefined error**. Also I am assigning datasource in another methid not same. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setDataSource()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/setdatasource) to set a dataSource to an initialized Kendo widget.

```
$('#myDropDown').kendoDropDownList({
    // options
}); 

let dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
    // options
});

$('#myDropDown').data('kendoDropDownList').setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $('<select class="dropdown"></select>')
        .appendTo($('body'))
        .kendoDropDownList();
    }
    
    let dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: ['Opt 1']
    });
    
    $('select.dropdown').each((i, el) => {
      $(el).data('kendoDropDownList').setDataSource(dataSource);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AKezOyok)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case some dropdown are initialized for e.g. at a time 5 dropdown are initialize and then need to set datasource and on some event other five dropdown need to initialize. Hope to listen from you again.

Comment: @NazneenSaiyed the solution i provided is to show how dataSource can be set to an already initialized widget. Therefore, that code will work in your case. You just need to adapt it. Now its up you.

Comment: If i initialize dropdown in one method and set datasource in another method, will it make any problem?? Bcoz in my case it is doing so

Comment: @NazneenSaiyed of course not. The example Im showing to you does exacly the same that is do the two things in separate ways, like you're saying. What is your problem actually ? Your question is too vague